# How to programmatically set a file field to allow multiple uploads/values?

Tags: 7, entities, files

I have created a file field with `field_create_field()` and added an instance of it to my custom node type with `field_create_instance()` in my module's `hook_install()`function. But how do I set it to allow unlimited file uploads. I can do it in the drupal interface by going to `structure > content types > manage fields` and clicking edit for my file field. I can set `number of values` on that page but how do I do it programmatically? There must some settings key I suppose but could not find it online.

I am using drupal 7.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

my example, see "cardinality" value:

```
$field = array(
  'field_name' => 'field_ws_file', 
  'type' => 'file',
  'cardinality' => FIELD_CARDINALITY_UNLIMITED,
);
field_create_field($field);
```

Instead of [FIELD_CARDINALITY_UNLIMITED](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!field!field.module/constant/FIELD_CARDINALITY_UNLIMITED/7) you could also simply use `-1`.